# Work with vscode

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I've been trying to debug my asp.net core application using vscode. So far I was able to build the application, but as soon as I run it, it fails with `Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.IO.FileSystem.dll` after loading `System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll`

Did anyone succeed on it? I will share my launch.json and tasks.json if anyone is interested. Note that whatever is marked using `<>` should be modified to your needs

`${workspaceRoot}` should be your src folder inside `aspnet-core` folder

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/<Web.Host-project-dir>/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/<Web.Host-.dll>",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "launchBrowser": {
                "enabled": true,
                "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
                "windows": {
                    "command": "cmd.exe",
                    "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
                },
                "osx": {
                    "command": "open"
                },
                "linux": {
                    "command": "xdg-open"
                }
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "dotnet",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [],
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build",
            "args": ["<Web.Host-project-dir>/<Web.Host-project-.csproj>" ],
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "showOutput": "silent",
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

The exception:

```
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\1.1.2\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.IO.FileSystem.dll
```

Comment: I have the same problem and can't find a solution for it. Have you?